# get attachment from private facebook messages, using fql

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-fql

How i can get attachments for my iOS app from facebook private messages, using fql?

i make FQL request:

> SELECT+body,attachment,source,created_time,author_id,message_id,viewer_id+FROM+message+WHERE+thread_id=%@

and receive the response:
but there is no relevant attachments.

```
{
    attachment =     {
        caption = "";
        description = "";
        "fb_object_id" = "";
        "fb_object_type" = "";
        icon = "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif";
        media =         (
        );
        name = "";
        properties =         (
        );
        "tagged_ids" =         (
        );
    };
    "author_id" = 100006578915973;
    body = "";
    "created_time" = 1392226769;
    "message_id" = "249232388588208_0";
    source = 32;
    "viewer_id" = 100002767455960;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get the name of the attachments, or the attachment files themselves downloadable for your user?

Comment: @KornélRegius I need link to messages attachments (images only)

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported and acknowledged Facebook FQL bug. It has been assigned, but is not fixed yet:

https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/447084618643204/